# ¿Por qué PHP me advierte "PHP Deprecated: Automatic conversion of false to array is deprecated"?

Tags: php, php8

Acabo de actualizar a PHP 8 y el log de errores está lleno de este mensaje:

> [23-Mar-2023 12:20:17 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Automatic conversion of
> false to array is deprecated in /..../boxes.php on line 380

La línea `380` es esta (estamos en el contexto de una clase):

```
$this->robots['noodp'] = true;
```

Investigando, encontré que [en la documentación](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/autovivification_false) PHP 8 quiso afrontar el problema llamado *autovivifación* que consistía en autocrear arrays con valores que podrían ser `false`  o `null`

Cuando revisé la clase, el campo `$robots` estaba declarado así:

```
public $robots=array();
```

Intentando corregir el problema (aunque en la línea `380` no se asigna `false` sino `true`, por tanto, no debería ser un problema de autovivifación), lo declaré así:

```
public array $robots;
```

Cuando hice eso, empezaron a salir advertencias de que un valor `false` no podía ser asignado a array o algo así, siempre en la misma línea `380`, de modo que declaré a `$robots` así:

```
public mixed $robots;
```

Al hacer eso, ocurren menos advertencias (de varias decenas de miles de entradas en el log, pasó a unas 3 mil líneas), pero siguen habiendo, y siempre en la misma dichosa línea `380`:

```
$this->robots['noodp'] = true;
```

No entiendo por qué sigue advirtiendo eso. Estuve revisando en las líneas más arriba de eso y hay un ternario hyper complicado en el cual sospecho que está el problema, pues la línea `380`, no es un caso de autovivifación, si es que entendí bien el problema.

Pongo aquí el código completo de la función:

```
public function preload() {
    global $thesis, $wp_query;
    $options = $thesis->api->get_options($this->_options(), $this->options);
    $page_type = $wp_query->is_archive ? ($wp_query->is_category ?
        'category' : ($wp_query->is_tag ?
        'post_tag' : ($wp_query->is_tax ?
        'tax' : ($wp_query->is_author ?
        'author' : ($wp_query->is_day ?
        'day' : ($wp_query->is_month ?
        'month' : ($wp_query->is_year ?
        'year' : false))))))) : false;
    $this->robots = !empty($this->post_meta['robots']) ?
        $this->post_meta['robots'] : (!empty($this->term_options['robots']) ?
        $this->term_options['robots'] : ($wp_query->is_home && empty($page_type) && !empty($options['blog']) && !empty($options['blog']['robots']) ?
        $options['blog']['robots'] : ($wp_query->is_search || $wp_query->is_404 ?
        array('noindex' => true, 'nofollow' => true, 'noarchive' => true) : (!empty($page_type) && !empty($options[$page_type]) && !empty($options[$page_type]['robots']) ?
        $options[$page_type]['robots'] : (!empty($options[$page_type]) ? $options[$page_type] : false)))));
    if (!empty($options['directory']) && !empty($options['directory']['noodp']))
        $this->robots['noodp'] = true; # Línea 380
    if (!empty($options['directory']) && !empty($options['directory']['noydir']))
        $this->robots['noydir'] = true; 
    if (!empty($this->robots) && !empty($this->robots['noindex']))
        add_filter('thesis_canonical_link', '__return_false');
}
```

Si alguien pudiera arrojar luz sobre esto se lo agradezco ... mi log de errores crece de una forma exponencial y tengo que irlo borrando, porque se está llenando de esta advertencia y quisiera resolverlo. Es un framework que no ha publicado código actualizado a PHP 8.

Comment: No sé si es el caso, pero creo que falta un paréntesis de cierre en `($wp_query->is_search || $wp_query->is_404 ?`.

Comment: @DjCrazy esos paréntesis cierran todos al final: `$options[$page_type] : false)))))` si intento lo contrario el sitio deja de funcionar porque el código resulta erróneo.

Comment: @A.Cedano el problema es que estas indicando que `$this->robots` puede resultar en `false`. Deberías reemplazar el `false` por `[]`. Y si esto causa problemas, entonces tendrías que asegurarte que solo asignes a `$this->robots[ALGO]` solo cuando `$this->robots` es un arreglo. PD1: también podes indicar que es `array` o `bool` al definir la variable: `public array|bool $robots;`. PD2: El mensaje solo se dispara cuando `this->robots` es un bool. [Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/580fc8)

Comment: @Marcos el error lo pude resolver poniendo esta anotación `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` a la clase que declara a `$robots`, la cosa quedó así: `#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class thesis_meta_robots extends thesis_box {
 public mixed $robots;` Investigando sobre la cantidad de errores que tenía encontré [esto](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/dynamic-properties-deprecated) y tuve que ponerlo en todas las clases que estaban dando problemas. Tengo una plantilla basada en Thesis que ya no recibe actualizaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano, es otra opción. Si bien no soluciona el hecho de que siga existiendo el "error/problema", evitas que se dispare el error y por ende no se escribe en el `error_log`. PD: No se que tan utilizado puede llegar a ser el framework y tambien depende la licencia que tenga... podes `forkear` y subir tu propia versión actualizada.

Comment: @Marcos sí. Dado que esa plantilla no recibe actualizaciones, la idea es migrar no muy tarde a otra plantilla basada en Bootstrap. El problema era que estos errores se escribían por miles y miles cada día en el log y necesita evitar eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano, no hace mucho me paso algo parecido. En un caso muy particular al generar un PDF se disparaba una advertencia, que nadie descubrio hasta que el `error_log` en menos de 1 hora llego a 180Gb.